# Ajax limit on post size

Tags: php, ajax

Background...

I'm using Handsontable.js to enable a user to manipulate a large number of rows of data.  There are 4 columns represented in the object below as 'id' , 'order' ,'no' , and 'name'.  When a user is satisfied with their edits, they will click a button and the data should be sent via ajax for processing.  The data looks like ...

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 194
                [drawing] => Array
                    (
                        [order] => 
                        [no] => A0001
                        [name] => -
                    )
            )

    )
```

Problem...

the data object contains 464 elements (this number will vary greatly).  Only 250 are received by the PHP script.

The Javascript....

```
function reorder(){
    var stuff = hot1.getData();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/listorder_processes.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { value: stuff },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

and the PHP...

```
$result = $_POST['value']
$count = count($result);
echo $count;
```

The result in the console is 250, while again 400+ items were sent.

My php.ini file has a `post_max_siz`e of 2000M - I dont think this is the issue.

I have considered comparing the original data object (that defines the data for the table) with the new data object (that which has been modified) - and only sending the pieces that have changed for processing, but the likelihood of that exceeding 250 is 100% - so I'm kind of stuck here.

Stringifying the object did not work.

Some similar posts also point to `max_input_vars`, but I'm not quite sure that's the problem either.

Scratch it - max input vars was the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: apache or nginx?  do you have access to those?  e.g. nginx also has a client_max_body_size setting.

Comment: have u tried getting count of what you are sending?

Comment: 250 was counted.  Increasing the php.ini variable "max_input_vars" from 1000 to 8000 fixed the issue.